# Set dynamic height to the block with JS

Tags: javascript

Transition does not work with height: auto.
So I need to calculate and set the block's dynamic height with JavaScript to make the transition property work.
This is an example of my code:

```
<div class="accordion__item">
   <div class="accordion__icon">
      <div class="accordion__content">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
const accItems = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

accItems.forEach((item) => {
  const icon = item.querySelector('.accordion__icon');
  const content = item.querySelector('.accordion__content');

    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (item.classList.contains('open')) {

    item.classList.remove('open');
    icon.classList.remove('open');
    content.classList.remove('open');
    
    } else {
    const accOpen = document.querySelectorAll('.open');

    accOpen.forEach((open) => {
    open.classList.remove('open');
    });

    item.classList.add('open');
    icon.classList.add('open');
    content.classList.add('open');
    }
    });
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal but there is not much we can do with transitioning height.

For a workaround, give your `open` class a `max-height` property that is larger than your expect the largest `open` element to get.  From there you can transition the `max-height` property.

There are also some optimizations you can make to your event listener callback.  I don't believe you need to add `open` to all the elements in the accordion, just the item itself.

Try something like this:

```
const accItems = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

accItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
       const openItems = document.querySelectorAll(".open")
       openItems.forEach(open => open.classList.toggle("open"))
       item.classList.toggle("open")
    }
});
```

Then in your css:

```
.open {
  max-height: 200px
}

.accordion__item {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 200ms ease;
}
```